# Shape's boundary doesn't move with it

Tags: swing, awt, translate, area, boundary

What I am trying to do is move a `java.awt.geom.Area` object on a JPanel. Then, by using a `java.awt.event.MouseAdapter` I want to check if the user clicked inside the moved area. The problem appears when I move the object - it appears in a correct position but its boudaries stay where they were initially. Is there any way to move the boundaries with the Area itself?

[image: The picture shows what I have and what I want]

Comment: How are you moving it? Are you keep a reference to the translated shape or not?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I do it by using g2.translate(x, y) where g2 is an object of Graphics2D and x and y are its coordinates.

Comment: `translate()` "Translates the origin of the graphics context…" Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that reproduces the problem you describe.

Comment: @M.Byenkov That won't change the shape, it will only translate where the graphics get drawn

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for your answer. Also, do you know if there is some way to move the boundary with the area?

Comment: @M.Byenkov That would depend on implementation details that we don't have, but `java.awt.geom.Area` can be [transformed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#transform-java.awt.geom.AffineTransform-)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Using AffineTransform did the thing! Thank you.